# Displaying each Asian characters in their own fonts?

Tags: customization

Suppose I have these two texts:

1. 고양이
2. 学ぶ猫

(1) is Korean, and (2) is Japanese, but the first character is a Japanese-simplified Chinese, the second character is Hiragana (Japanese's own character), and the third is traditional Chinese. In Japan, Chinese letters are used, and many of them are the same as traditional Chinese like "猫" and some of them are simplified like "学".

Anyway, if I use them in an application like Krita (for layers), they are displayed correctly.

[image]

If I use them in Blender (for objects), by default they look like this:

[image]

If I change the interface font in the settings to a Japanese font like "Meiryo", it looks like below. The Japanese text is displayed correctly, but the Korean text is still boxes.

[image]

If I change the interface font in the settings to a Korean font like "Malgun gothic", it looks like below. The Korean text is displayed correctly, but the Japanese-simplified Chinese is a box. This is because Japanese-simplified Chinese is not usually used in Korea and probably the font does not contain them. Hiragana (the second letter, ぶ) is displayed, but is ugly. For some reason, the Korean code contains Japanese Kana's as special characters, but usually the Kana in Korean fonts are ugly and disproportionate. I do not want to see Kanas in a Korean font. The third letter 猫 is displayed correctly because Korean also uses traditional Chinese, but in my opinion, Japanese fonts usually have better-looking tradiontional Chinese letters than Korean fonts.

[image]

So, the ideal result for me is that the whole Japanese text is displayed in a Japanese font like Meiryo, and the the Korean font is displayed in a Korean font like Malgun Gothic like below (this is not a screen capture; I composited the two screen captures above). Is this possible with Blender?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know this is not currently possible, unless you find a font containing both glyph sets. Maybe combine them in some editor

Comment: Thanks. If it is impossible, I think I could combine fonts. I think I read about combining fonts before, though I do not remember how to. Ideally, the best result for me would be starting from an English font, add Japanese and Chinese characters from Meiryo, and then add Korean characters from Malgun Gothic. I will search the web for a tool for doing that...

Comment: Maybe FontForge can help, though I never tried mysef

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally discovered this but, I could get the result I wanted by just checking the "Translation" checkbox in Interface in the Preference dialogue. Blender's version is 2.81a.

[image]

Even though "Translation" is checked, it did not change the UI language from English. I wonder why this option is turned on by default. Maybe there is some side effects like slow UI or something? I will add here if I later discover some problems with this, but so far, it seems working.

---

**Update**

There seems to be a big problem. When it is checked, Blender seems to be using "international fonts". But that makes zooming on the Shade Editor very slow. It is not unusably slow, but makes it unpleasant to use Blender. I tried to report it as a bug, but found an [existing entry for this](https://developer.blender.org/T46463). The entry was closed because it is an "old known TODO", meaning the developers are currently do not have the time to fix this and will not fix this.

Blender is probably written in OpenGL, and I don't know why zooming of a few lines of texts should be this slow just because "international fonts" are used, because web browsers like Chrome zooms fine with Asian fonts, but anyway, I think I will only check the "Translation" when I have to open someone else's file that used Asian texts for the names of objects.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your research :). Please mark your answer as accepted **✓**, so others can easily find it.